# HR did not ask for passport during inverview

Tags: interviewing, human-resources, united-kingdom

Today I went through an assessment day for a Graduate Software Engineer position. The whole process consisted of around 5 interviews including behavioural as well as technical ones.

In the last interview, the Development Head said that I should wait in this room for the HR person just in case they need some additional information etc.

However, he came back 5 minutes later saying I will take you to wait for them in the Reception. The HR person came with one other candidate (we were just 2 candidates at this day) and just said goodbye to us.

I asked the other candidate if they asked for his passport and he said yes they did. However, they did not ask for mine.
In the confirmation email for the assessment day they had mentioned that we should take documents that prove our eligibility to work in the U.K.

Does that mean I have already been rejected?

Any answers would be much appreciated.

Thank you!

Comment: I'm not sure any of us can answer this with any degree of certainty. Good luck with your job search.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because There is no way we can know if this was an oversight or due to HR screening.

Comment: It means they forgot to check your passport. If you get hired you will be asked to bring your passport on the first day to work.

Comment: This is a good question.  HR can't ask specifically for your passport if you are asking about proving citizenship, they must accept any documents for an I-9 form, see https://www.uscis.gov/i-9 for more details.  This commonly happens on site on your first day.

If you are not a citizen, then they would ask for your EAD card.

Comment: However, for UK citizens and currently EU citizens the passport is the easiest, and often the only, evidence they have. Especially UK citizens would typically have no other proof since they don't need it.

Comment: You're asking for our opinions. We don't know. Your guess is as good as ours. Maybe they simply offered the job to the other guy and if the other guy refuses, they might offer it to you, in which case you'll need to bring your passport with you if you do take the job. Who knows!

Answer (score 2):

I don't see how anyone here could know if the HR person didn't ask for your passport because they had already eliminated you and it would have been superfluous, or if they just forgot. I know it can be stressful waiting for an answer for something like this, but try to just calm down and wait patiently. In the meantime, continue applying elsewhere.